# consecutive operators and brackets

Tags: perl, syntax, operators, brackets, curly-brackets

I'm just trying to learn a bit of Perl and have come across this:

```
foreach $element (@{$records})
{
    do something;
}
```

To my newbie eyes, this reads: 
    "for each element in an array named @{$records}, do something" 
but, since that seems an unlikely name for an array (with "`@{$`" altogether), I imagine it isn't that simple?

I've also come across "`%$`" used together.
I know `%` signifies a hash and `$` signifies a scalar but don't know what they mean together.

Can anyone shed any light on these?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Perl you can have a reference (a pointer) to a data structure:

```
# an array
my @array;

# a reference to an array
my $ref = \@array;
```

When you have a reference to be able to *use* the array you need to **dereference** it

```
@{ $ref }
```

If you need to access an element as in

```
$array[0]
```

you can do the same with a reference

```
${$ref}[0]
```

The curly brackets `{}` are optional and you can also use

```
$$ref[0]
@$ref
```

but I personally find them less readable.

The same applies to every other type (as `%$` for a hash reference).

See [man perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for the details and [man perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for a tutorial.

**Edit**

The arrow operator `->` can also be used to dereference an array or an hash

```
$array_ref->[0]
```

or

```
$hash_ref->{key}
```

See [man perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for details

Comment: I prefer to access a single element in an array reference with `$array->[0]`

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera Thanks (I completely forgot but it is worth to mention it as it is widely used especially with hashes). I updated the answer.

Comment: 3 or is it 4 ways to get an array element when given an array reference. I wonder how many there are in Perl 6? 3 ways gets a little confusing.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a reference to an array or a hash, you would use a scalar to hold the reference:

```
my $href = \%hash;
my $aref = \@array;
```

When you want to de-reference these references, you would use the symbol appropriate for the reference type:

```
for my $element (@$aref) {
}

for my $key (keys %$href) {
}
```